# editing document and field in firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

im working on firebase and im trying to update the document name and its field name together like shown in the image. i want them to be updated together.

[image]

i used this code

```
    EditCourse(String cName, String newName) async {
  var collection = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("Courses")
    ..where("Course name", isEqualTo: cName);
  collection.doc(cName).update({'Course name': newName});
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to update the document ID of an existing document. If changing course names is a use-case you need to support, consider using Firestore's built-in [ID generation when adding your documents](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#add_a_document) (so add documents using the `add()` method).

If you stick to your current model, you'll have to:

1. Read the existing document.
2. Write the date under the new ID.
3. Delete the original document.

Given the type of operation, you'll probably want to [use a transaction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions) for that.

Answer (score 1):

Answer:
As of Now Firebase not allows to update documents ids)

Suggestion:
You should use relational ids or random ids
(relational ids means suppose you have seller favorite collection you can give documents ids to movie/food ids)